# Did Harry Potter ever get food for his birthday?

Tags: harry-potter

I seem to remember Harry Potter getting food for his birthday. What food(s) did he get and from whom?

Comment: Harry has also accidentally got an ice cream and part of a “knicker-bocker glory” (whatever food that meant) for Dudley's tenth birthday.

Comment: Is there some *magical significance* to getting food for his birthday? Otherwise, this seems no different from asking "Did Harry get a pocketknife for his birthday", or "Does Harry have string in his pocket", etc. There could be a million potential questions about any book, that are just... irrelevant.

Comment: Might be an indirect way of asking when he got cake for his birthday, or any cake-like gifts he might have received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Food items

- In *Philosopher's Stone* (As *apporv020* notes in [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4677/20774)), Harry was given a **large, sticky chocolate birthday cake with green iced lettering** by Hagrid.
- In *Chamber of Secrets* Harry receives nothing for his birthday because Dobby is intercepting Harry's mail.
- He doesn't receive food in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, unless *The Monster Book of Monsters* could be considered edible, which I think not.
- In *Goblet of Fire* (as *Pearsonartphoto* notes in [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4665/20774)), Harry receives **four superb birthday cakes** from Ron, Hermione, Hagrid, and Sirius respectively.
- In *Order of the Phoenix*, Harry receives **two boxes of Honeyduke's best chocolate** from Ron and Hermione, but ends up tossing them out in a fit of pique when no one writes or contacts him during the summer holidays.
- In *Half-Blood Prince* Mrs. Weasley has **a birthday tea** for Harry **with birthday cake.**
- In *Deathly Hallows* Mrs Weasley gives Harry **a birthday dinner complete with a large beach ball-sized birthday cake decorated as a Golden Snitch**.

These are all the birthday-related food references I could find.

Comment: Very nice summary of all sources of food for Harry's Birthday...and a very good answer to a very peculiarly specific question.

Comment: Harry also gets fudge (along with Weasley jumper) from Mrs Weasley for PS Christmas :)

Comment: @DVK - I want a Weasley sweater for myself! (And fudge too)

Comment: @Slytherincess - No accounting for tastes... but Mrs. Fudge might object *bada-bing\*

Answer (score 9):

The most conspicuous example occurred in book 4, where he got food when Dudley was forced on a diet. This included cake and other junk type foods for the most part, from Hagrid, the Weasleys, Hermione, and Sirius, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

Also include the chocolate cake on his eleventh birthday.

Comment: And a cappuccino on his 17th birthday.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: True, and no thanks to the Dudleys either.

Comment: He didn't get the cappucino in the book; he was under the Invisibility Cloak so it would have looked odd to order a third coffee that inexplicably disappears when the waitress turns her back.

Comment: It also wasn't his birthday in the book.